# HTTP 404 resource not found when project run on server on spring tool suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

It was all working fine until I made some changes that I can't seem remember in order to revert. I changed the the dynamic web module version and the java version to their latest respective versions in project facets. Then I made some changes to the 'pom.xml' file by adding latest versions of the jar files. I cannot seem to understand what isn't working.

**pom.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
    <name>EMusicStore</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>

            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value=" jdbc:h2:~/test" />
            <property name="username" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan">
                <list>
                    <value>com.store.emusicstore</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            </bean>
            <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
                <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            </bean>

</beans>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"


xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/webapp/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.store.emusicstore" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.store.emusicstore;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.store.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
import com.store.emusicstore.model.Product;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    private ProductDao productDao ;
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productList")
    public String getProduct(Model model)
    {
        List<Product> productList = productDao.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("productList" ,productList);
        return "ProductList";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/productList/viewProduct/{productId}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable String productId, Model model) throws IOException{

        Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
        model.addAttribute(product);
        return "viewProduct";
    }

}
```

Is changing the web app version from 2.5 to 3.1 the cause?

Comment: If have the same problem with Scala's sbt:[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/Build%C6%92orce/IdeaProjects/GreenTrac-Backend/}greentrac-backend...
[info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.4.194 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.h2database#h2;1.4.194
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Public\AppData\Local\.ivy2\local\com.h2database\h2\1.4.194\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.194/h2-1.4.194.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.1 ...

Comment: It doesn't seem like the same problem as mine. I know mine has something to do with changing versions of dynamic module or some other dependency. Because it was working just fine before. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: It seems that https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.194/h2-1.4.194.pom is missing on the maven.org server since a while.

Comment: What should I try to replace the dependency with then?

Comment: Btw its not even loading my homepage. The url isn't even pointing to the home request url. Is there something wrong with my servlet-context.xml file?

Comment: The  repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.194/h2-1.4.194.‌​pom is replaced by version h2 1.4.195, so by http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.195/h2-1.4.195.pom this is closed.

Comment: Still did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to solve the problem.It wasn't able to find the web.xml because it was mistakenly placed inside the 'views' folder instead of directly being under the WEB-INF folder.